# Nested for loop python

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to print items from two lists respectively. I wrote code as below:

```
 for i in list_a:
     for j in list_b:
     print(str(i) + str(j))
```

The ideal result would be "A1 + B1", "A2 + B2", etc. However, the lines above only field the last item in list_b. When I indent the print statement further:

```
for i in list_a:
    for j in list_b:
        print(str(i) + str(j))
```

The result does not seem to be correct. I know this is a really basic for loop question, but I am very confused by the ways the outputs differ.

Comment: Can you share sample values for `list_a` and `list_b` and the result you'd like to get for them?

Comment: But the first block of code will give you a syntax error? Can you please clarify?

Comment: `for i,j in zip(list_a, list_b): print(i+j)`

Comment: I tried your first code and it gave me `IndentationError: expected an indented block`. What code are you actually running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using zip?

```
for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b):
    print('%s + %s' % (a, b))
```

Zip merges two or more lists together into tuples, e.g.:

```
zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]) # [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Also, when you do `print(a + b)`, you simply add the strings together, which means concat. E.g. if `a` was `"a"` and `b` was `"b"`, `a + b` would produce `"ab"` and not `"a + b"` like you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding another answer because no one has explained why this code doesn't work.  Which seems to me what the OP was actually looking for.

**Your Solution 1**:

```
for i in list_a:
     #This indentation is inside 'i' loop
     for j in list_b:
          #This indentation is inside 'j' loop  
     print(str(i) + str(j))
```

Will step through `list_a`, and for every iteration, step through all of `list_b` (as there's nothing in the `list_b` code block, nothing will happen for each step) THEN print, so it will print out for every `i` in `list_a` and `j` will always be the number of the last item of `list_b` as it's stepped through the whole thing.

Although this code probably will not run anyway as there is an empty code block and the compiler will likely pick that up with an `IndentationError`

**Your Solution 2**:

```
for i in list_a:
    for j in list_b:
        print(str(i) + str(j))
```

Will step through all of `list_a` and for each element, step through all of `list_b` so you will end up with `A1B1`, `A1B2`, `A1B3`, etc`.

**Preferred Solution**

The solution is to step through both lists at the same time, at the same rate which [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1663826/2075524) covers nicely, with essentially the same solution as @Pavlins answer.